# Display on TV using HDMI on laptop and TV

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv

What settings on laptop are needed to get connection from Acer Travelmate 5730G hdmi port to hdmi tv to work. PC monitor works well with the laptop, but no luck with HDMI

Answer (score 1):

Try the Fn key and whichever of the F keys has a little picture of a screen - to turn on external monitor

Then check the resolution of the external screen, probably either 1920x1080 or 1280x720